# Getting "Invalid checksum" in Paytm in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, paytm

I am integerating Paytm Integeration in ios swift5

After following google links i am getting this error. Searched on the internet but the solution is not provided for this issue.

This is my response, I am using  staging MID and other credentials.

Please provide a solution!

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-I'><title>Paytm</title><script type='text/javascript'>function response(){return document.getElementById('response').value;}</script></head><body>Redirect back to the app<br><form name='frm' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='response' name='responseField' value='{"ORDERID":"WvE9q", "MID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX210", "TXNAMOUNT":"100.00", "CURRENCY":"INR", "STATUS":"TXN_FAILURE", "RESPCODE":"330", "RESPMSG":"Invalid checksum", "BANKTXNID":""}' /></form></body></html>

 PayTmIntegration[2222:92868]    response() JS method returned = {"ORDERID":"WvE9q", "MID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX210", "TXNAMOUNT":"100.00", "CURRENCY":"INR", "STATUS":"TXN_FAILURE", "RESPCODE":"330", "RESPMSG":"Invalid checksum", "BANKTXNID":""}
```

Calling Delegate didFinishedResponse

```
{

  "RESPMSG" : "Invalid checksum",

  "STATUS" : "TXN_FAILURE",

  "TXNAMOUNT" : "100.00",

  "BANKTXNID" : "",

  "MID" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX210",

  "RESPCODE" : "330",

  "CURRENCY" : "INR",

  "ORDERID" : "WvE9q"

}
```

PGTransactionViewController::viewWillDisappear

Comment: Please be more specific. Nobody can really go through this much text.

Comment: Hi @Grayrigel i am getting Invalid checksum in response . Has anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: Try reaching out to Paytm folks. They might be able to help you out.

Comment: Can anyone please share the working link for paytm integeration with lattest version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the checksum using the correct params. The checksum generation logic is explained on developer docs of paytm. Also please confirm which checkout flow are you integrating? Use the latest flow given by Paytm.